# Kivy matplotlib inside a tab

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I want to display matplotlib plots from kivy.garden in a kivy gui in separate tabs after clicking a button. However, after clicking the button nothing happens:

From kv-File (shorted):
The button:

```
Button:
    text: "Plot"
    on_release: Factory.Controller(1).plot_dc()
```

Tabs:

```
<Controller>:
    do_default_tab: False
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "DC Signals"
        id: dc
```

From my python file (I shorted it to the relevant part; plotting and creating axes and fig objects alone works perfectly).

```
class Controller(TabbedPannel):
    def __init__(self, max_size, **kwargs):
        TabbedPanel.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def plot_dc(self):
        self.ids.dc.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(Controller.figs["DC Signals"]))

class ControllerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Controller(1000)
```

I also tested adding a button to the tab (with add_widget), but this didn't work either. It seems to be a problem with my tabs in general.

Comment: It looks like your `Button` release is creating a new `Controller` instance and calling its `plot_dc()` method, but the newly created `Controller` is not used anywhere. You need to add it to your GUI somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that makes. I got rid of this with changing the creation to a call to the controller object, which is the root: app.root.plot_dc(). However, it still doesn't work.